# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll') <nodejs>

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, typeerror, undefined

I was trying to make an API using Node.js and Sequelize (MySQL). The API has many models and associations. I made migrations after making the models.
Now that I'm making the service file, when I make a request to the login route, I encounter that error.
I have tried many things and read a lot of guides for this issue. But I still have that.

(Typos checked!)  --  (The modules imported properly)

Could you please suggest me a solution?
I appreciate you in advance!

**Error**

```
    const results = await db.user.findOne({where:{phoneNumber: body.phoneNumber}})
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')
    at login (C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Learning\Mafia-api\user\user.service.js:5:35)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Learning\Mafia-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Learning\Mafia-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Learning\Mafia-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Learning\Mafia-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Learning\Mafia-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Learning\Mafia-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Learning\Mafia-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Learning\Mafia-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
    at router (C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Learning\Mafia-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**Model: user.js**

```
    module.exports = async (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const user = await sequelize.define('users', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },

        phoneNumber: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },

        displayName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        }
    })

    user.association = model => {
        user.hasMany(model.currencyWallet);

        user.hasMany(model.userSetting);

    }
    return user
}
```

**Service: user.service.js**

```
const db = require('../models');

async function login(req, res) {
    const body = req.body;
    const results = await db.user.findOne({where:{phoneNumber: body.phoneNumber}})
    res.json({
        success: 0,
        message: 'Results found!'
    })
}

module.exports = {
    login
}
```

**Index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const userRouter = require('./user/user.router');
const PORT = 5000 
const HOST = 'localhost'
const db = require('./models');

app.use(express.json());

app.use('/', userRouter);

db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`));
})
```

**config.json**

```
  "development": {
    "username": "xxxx",
    "password": xxxx,
    "database": "nameofthegamegoeshere",
    "host": "xxx.x.x.x",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fortunately found the solution of my problem myself!
It took me a lot of time and effort to find the problem and debug it but it's not a very complicated problem!

In one of my models, ***user.js*** that I mentioned earlier, I was using async/await syntax to define a table.
*IT'S NOT TRUE ...*

After I **removed** the **async/await** from my model, ***user.js*** file, the problem gone away!

So, ***user.js*** should be like this (without any async/await expression):

### -- Solution --

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const user = sequelize.define('users', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },

        phoneNumber: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },

        displayName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        }
    })

    user.association = model => {
        user.hasMany(model.currencyWallet);

        user.hasMany(model.userSetting);

    }
    return user
}
```

### Explanation

This problem occurred because I had some issue to understand how Javascript Promises work.

I recommend to read more about 1- Callback functions and 2- Promises respectively in order to understand the issue and it's solution. Specially if you're also a beginner like me :)

This is one of the useful resources to check:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises

When I use async/await to make a model, It returns a **Promise**.

```
const user = await sequelize.define('users', {some-code-in-here})
```

Then the promise state turns to **<"pending">**. It means that something is on process or we are waiting...

Because the state of that promise is on "pending", no result object would be expected to be in ***user*** and as the result, the value of user will be **undefined**.

This is the reason that the error says: "It can't read properties of **undefined**".

Once the promise state turns to **"settled"**, it will return a ***result*** (when succeeds) or an ***error*** (when fails).
But in this case, the state of that promise is still on "pending" when the program  use it as ***user***.

By removing async/await, it will immediately executes the define() function and put the result in ***user***. So there is no problem to make use of ***user*** anymore.

~ I hope this post can help to solve many people's problem and saves a lot of time :) ~

Answer (score 0):

In Model: user.js you are definign the model as ***users***

But in user.service.js you're calling the model as user

Change this line in User model

```
...

 const user = await sequelize.define('users', 

...
```

To this line

```
const user = await sequelize.define('user',... // should be user, not users
```

Hope it'll fix your problem.

Comment: I have tried this before and tried it again, it doesn't work. It seems that something is wrong with promises somewhere. The 'db' returns undefiend: Promise {<pending>}. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Mr.Moeini can you please add the source code how you're setting up sequelize?

Here's a git repo that I've implemented sequelize with node js and MySql https://github.com/ArmAlam/node-boilderplate

Comment: Do you mean the config.js file?

Comment: yes. the config.js file.

Comment: I added the only part of the config file that I had configured

Answer (score 0):

**db.user.findOne** error goes here so is db.user really get to database?
i think use import seprate as `**const user = require('../models').user**`
and then use
**user.findall()**